# Essentially Undecidable Theories

Tags: logic, incompleteness

Are there essentially undecidable theories the essential undecidability of which has not been established through a Gödel Sentence, that is, by diagonalization?

To the best of my knowledge, the answer is "no". All essentially undecidable theories seem to go back to Gödel's diagonalizazion technique. It is remarkable, or puzzling, that since the publication of Gödel's incompleteness article in 1931, the essential undecidability of some theories has not been established by other means than Gödel's diagonalization.

---

EDIT *(not by OP)*: A theory is **essentially undecidable** if (it is consistent and) all its models have undecidable theories. This is equivalent to the (in my experience) more common term **essential incompleteness**, meaning that all recursively axiomatizable extensions of the theory are incomplete; see e.g. [here](http://www1.cuni.cz/~svejdar/papers/sv_ybk07.pdf).

Comment: I'm not sure why this got a downvote - I've upvoted to compensate.

Comment: Here's a very weak positive observation: Kripke gave a proof ([written up by Putnam](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1027953483)) of the incompleteness of PA without using diagonalization. He introduced a notion of "fulfillability," and showed that the sentence "The conjunction of the first $n$ axioms of PA is fulfillable, for all $n$" is independent of PA. But we can in fact (and Putnam observes this) modify the argument slightly to conclude that *no finitely axiomatizable extension* of PA is both consistent and complete. Of course this isn't essential incompleteness, but still - neat!

Comment: I've added a definition of the term "essential undecidability," and voted to reopen. (I personally feel that it **is** appropriate to take this term for granted in such a question, but it seems that's not commonly shared, so I've erred on the side of explicitness.)

Comment: Thanks,  Noah Schweber, for precising the meaning of "essentially incomplete" or "essentially undecidable". I should have done it myself. "Essentially incomplete" is, in my opinion, a better name. I used "essentially undecidable" because, to the best of my knowledge, the notion has been introduced under this name by Andrzej Mostowski, Raphael M. Robinson and Alfred Tarski in the chapter "Undecidability and Essential Undecidability in Arithmetic" of the book "Undecidable Theories", Tarski editor, North-Holland, 1953.